# Save/bake Transformed texture

Tags: image, texture-baking

[image: Save image after done editing in edit mode.]

i imported a PNG image in blender using import as plane addon. after importing i added some loopcuts to adjust it. Now i want to bake it again to save it in other software.

Comment: Can't you simply render it as an image?

Comment: is there any simple way to save it because i do it regularly, rendering image will also add specularity.

Comment: I don't think so, but I must admit I've never had any reason to try to use Blender for that. To be honest I'd have thought that almost any other image software would be more suitable than Blender for simply manipulating the shape of an image.

Comment: You can of course use the òverlays`button to disable any linses of the loopcut and then save a screenshot. But still, the imported image itself looks a bit "dull" compared to the original display  of the image file. This seems similar to a result of rendering the image out.